# git config does not set vimdiff layout properly, git 2.39

Tags: git, vimdiff

I'm trying to configure vimdiff as a git merge tool, so my global git config contains the following lines:

```
[merge]
    tool = gvimdiff
    guitool = gvimdiff
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[mergetool "gvimdiff"]
    layout = "LOCAL,MERGED,REMOTE"
```

but I am keep in having the default layout.
A similar problem has reported [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38251/git-config-does-not-set-vimdiff-layout-properly) but it won't apply to my case because of the following reasons:

1. I am using gvimdiff
2. I am using git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)

How should I solve it?
Running on MacOsX Ventura.

Answer (score 1):

That should be fixed with Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f9d4d28b7e6021b7e6db192b7bf47bd3a0d0d1d): variants of vimdiff learned to honor `mergetool.<variant>.layout` settings.

See [commit b21d164](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b21d164275b9186421ebe39498be47ea9f171694) (17 Feb 2024) by [Kipras Melnikovas (`kiprasmel`)](https://github.com/kiprasmel).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 66b1160](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66b1160141fc9c5ea01c473aaef4e6a5c8532ec5), 27 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`mergetools`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b21d164275b9186421ebe39498be47ea9f171694): vimdiff: use correct tool's name when reading mergetool config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kipras Melnikovas</sup>

> The `/mergetools/vimdiff` script, which handles both `vimdiff`, `nvimdiff` and `gvimdiff` mergetools (the latter 2 simply source the `vimdiff` script), has a function `merge_cmd()` which read the layout variable from [`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b21d164275b9186421ebe39498be47ea9f171694/Documentation/git-config.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup>, and it would always read the value of `mergetool.**vimdiff**.layout`, instead of the mergetool being currently used (`vimdiff` or `nvimdiff` or `gvimdiff`).
>
> It looks like in [7b5cf8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b5cf8be180940ce099c8413d02fb5707d900708) ("`vimdiff`: add tool documentation", 2022-03-30, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/123dfdff0d6e886ce5536d39dd77dcd46db8d4c0)), we explained the current behavior in `Documentation/config/mergetool.txt`:
>
> ```
>     The vimdiff backend uses this variable to control how its split
>     windows look like. Applies even if you are using Neovim (`nvim`) or
>     gVim (`gvim`) as the merge tool. See BACKEND SPECIFIC HINTS section
> ```
>
> which makes sense why it's explained this way - the vimdiff backend is used by gvim and nvim.
> But the mergetool's configuration should be separate for each tool, and indeed that's confirmed in same commit at `Documentation/mergetools/vimdiff.txt`:
>
> ```
> ## Variants  
>
> Instead of `--tool=vimdiff`, you can also use one of these other variants:
> * `--tool=gvimdiff`, to open gVim instead of Vim.
> * `--tool=nvimdiff`, to open Neovim instead of Vim.  
>
> When using these variants, in order to specify a custom layout you will have to set configuration variables `mergetool.gvimdiff.layout` and `mergetool.nvimdiff.layout` instead of `mergetool.vimdiff.layout`
> ```
>
> So it looks like we just forgot to update the 1 part of the `vimdiff` script that read the config variable.
> Cheers.
>
> Though, for backward compatibility, I've kept the `mergetool.vimdiff` fallback, so that people who unknowingly relied on it, won't have their setup broken now.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b21d164275b9186421ebe39498be47ea9f171694/Documentation/config/mergetool.txt#L48-L59):

> ### `mergetool.<vimdiff variant>.layout`
>
> Configure the split window layout for vimdiff's `<variant>`, which is any of `vimdiff`,
> `nvimdiff`, `gvimdiff`.
> Upon launching `git mergetool` with `--tool=<variant>` (or without `--tool`
> if `merge.tool` is configured as `<variant>`), Git will consult
> `mergetool.<variant>.layout` to determine the tool's layout.
>
> If the
> variant-specific configuration is not available, `vimdiff`'s is used as
> fallback.
> If that too is not available, a default layout with 4 windows
> will be used.
>
> To configure the layout, see the `BACKEND SPECIFIC HINTS` section of git-mergetool.

`mergetools/vimdiff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b21d164275b9186421ebe39498be47ea9f171694/Documentation/mergetools/vimdiff.txt#L180-L181):

> `mergetool.nvimdiff.layout` instead of `mergetool.vimdiff.layout` (though the
> latter will be used as fallback if the variant-specific one is not set).